# What does "beanspruchungsgerecht" mean?

Tags: translation, german-to-english, meaning-in-context, technical-terminology

This is the context:

> Vorteile des Werkstoffs: Grauguß
>
> Im Gießverfahren leicht formbar, deshalb kann man Gußgestelle ohne
> Mehrkosten **beanspruchungsgerecht** gestalten

I understand that **beanspruch** can mean a **stress**, **load** or **demand**, and **gerecht** in technical contexts means **compatible**.

Translation attempt:

> Advantages of the material: Cast Iron
>
> In casting processes easily ductile, hence cast iron frames can be
> formed without expensive stress analysis.

Comment: Are you an engineer? The advantage of casting is that you can quite easily manufacture a part with dimensions very close to the desired final dimensions (I admit *formbar* is not the wisest choice in the German text, but *ductile* is definitely the wrong translation), and hence the parts do not require extensive machining to give them their final shape. So of course you need expensive stress analysis to figure out what the part should look like exactly, but you do not have to spend a lot of money on manufacturing that part (especially very many identical parts).

Answer (score 12):

By using the suffix *"-gerecht"* we can build an adjective from a noun to expresses that something meets criteria for defined usage (*"Etwas wird seiner Sache gerecht"*).

In a technical context from cast iron I would translate "*Beanspruchung*" with *strain*.

Thus "*Beanspruchungsgerecht*" would translate to something like: "*to meet requirements for strain*"

Comment: Engineers combine many other words with the suffix "-gerecht": Montagegerecht, Fertigungsgerecht are examples, the translations are analogous to "Beanspruchungsgerecht".

Answer (score 9):

I'd also interpret *beanspruchungsgerecht* as referring to the intensitivity of usage the object will be subject to.

The following quote suggests that *load-dependent* is a translation for *beanspruchungsgerecht*:

> Verfahren zur Herstellung beanspruchungsgerecht verschleissfester, rotierend bewegter Draht-, Seil- und/oder Drahtseillaufflaechen, insbesondere Oberflaechen von Drahtziehtrommeln aus Drahtziehmaschinen oder aehnlichen Transportrollen oder Trommeln
>
> Process for the production of load-dependent, wear-resistant, wire, rope and/or wire cable running surfaces moved in rotation, in particular surfaces of wire pulling drums in wire pulling machines or similar transport rollers or drums

The following, though specific for packaging, provides a definition for *beanspruchungsgerecht*:

> Beanspruchungsgerecht ist eine Verpackung, die unter Berücksichtigung von Versandbelastungen, Versandweg, Versanddauer und Transportbelastungsprofil sicherstellt, dass das Packgut ohne Schaden den Empfänger erreicht.

It is *beanspruchungsgerecht* if it will endure over the expected usage scenario and life time.

I'm not sure with your translation, since it focuses on the requirement of stress analysis. To me, it seems that the important thing is that you can create the forms freely (i.e. according to your usage requirements). Of course, *not requiring expensive stress analysis* can be interpreted to the same :)

Comment: I'd be curious to know how you found that German-English translation containing "beanspruchungsgerecht". I tried http://linguee.com but there were no results. Are there alternatives?

Comment: @edelstein: [This Fraunhofer article](http://publica.fraunhofer.de/dokumente/PX-39153.html) was on my second results page for the Google search for "beanspruchungsgerecht". It has (at least for the introduction) both languages :)

Answer (score 1):

I looked it up in Linguee myself, and it seems in the meantime many translations have appeared. (Some of them are plain nonsense.)

Here are three which I find are good.

> Grundsätzlich müssen Maschinen, die in Containern verladen werden, **beanspruchungsgerecht** verpackt werden.
>
> Machinery which is to be shipped in containers must always be provided with packaging which is **fit for purpose**.
>
> ---
>
> In der Prozesssimulation unterstützen wir unsere Partner, Werkzeuge **beanspruchungsgerecht** auszulegen und Prozessführungen zu verbessern.
>
> Our simulations help our partners to improve the design of their tools **in line with the subsequent operating conditions** and improve the process controls.
>
> ---
>
> Die mechanisch-technologischen Eigenschaften der Triebwerkscheiben werden **beanspruchungsgerecht** eingestellt und weisen eine sehr geringe Streuung auf.
>
> The mechanical properties of the turbine disks **are matched exactly to stress requirements** and display high uniformity.

Note that there is no uniform translation for *beanspruchungsgerecht*. Rather, the wording in English depends on context.

I am wondering, however, could *beanspruchungsgerecht* not simply be always translated like in the first example, "*fit for purpose*"? But then I suppose the sentences would probably not be any more *fachsprachlichkeitsgerecht*.